# Horizontal orientation is not working unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I´ve been developing a sort of flappy bird game and decided that I want to be able to play it on mobile. I set up the unity remote and tried it out, but came to the realisation that the game was vertical, and not horizontal, as I had planned. I tried looking up some tutorials but it didnt help.

I tried using the unity function designed specifically for that, in project preferences and set them to the horizontal ones, but it did nothing. I also checked in case my phone was the problem and I had accidentally left on the not rotation option, but it wasn´t the case either. Maybe changing the screen width and height could help but I don´t remember how to do it ad don´t thonk it will woek. Also, for some reason, in the android version (I started making it for windows) the text looks a lot bigger, but I fear that if I change it there, it will also be changed for the other devices.

Comment: Have you set the default orientation in the player settings? [Player Settings Android](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I hadn´t seen the option before. Do you have any idea of what could be causing the letters being bigger there? And also, the game still looks quite stretched. How do you make it not be?

Comment: That is too much to answer in a passing comment.  Here is relevant information, [Designing UI For Multiple Resolutions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)